# Flash ошибки при валидации yii2

Tags: php, yii2

После нажатия кнопки отправить форму, если какие-то reuired поля не заполнены, в response приходят данные о полях, которые нужно заполнить. Можно как-то показать эти ошибки, но только в отдельном блоке, или к примеру flash -

`foreach($model->errors as $error) Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $error);`

Как можно это сделать? Вот такой код контроллера, ajax валидация

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new ObjectForm();
        $model->scenario = 'create';

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->saveObject()) {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            return $this->render('/objects/create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ну ответ у вас уже формируется, поэтому нужно ловить его на фронте и показывать как вам нужно и где вам нужно.

Можно перехватывать все, и отфильтровать нужный

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
  console.log(settings.url, jqxhr.responseText);
});
```

Либо попробовать вывести ошибки в нужном вам блоке

```
<?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

Либо так попробовать перехватить события

```
$('#object-form').on('afterValidate', function (event, messages, errorAttributes) {
   console.log(event, messages, errorAttributes);
}).on('ajaxComplete', function (event, jqXHR, textStatus){
    console.log(event, messages, errorAttributes);
});
```

Всё зависит от конкретной реализации, и количества форм у вас на странице